# Help with setting up AIM account

Tags: empathy

Can anyone help me configure my AIM account? I have Oneiric and I want to set up my AIM account with what I believe is a chat client (the envelope icon on the top right). It is called Empathy. \n
I tried to do this using Broadcast Account. It let me choose what account (Jabber, Pidgin, Aim, etc...). Once I entered my password for my AIM account, I got a pop-up asking for the master password for my Keyring. I didn't know what that was at the time so I closed that window after trying to enter my account password. Keyring apparently asks for a master password and it holds any keys you want to remember in the future. It gave me an error so I couldn't set up my AIM account completely. Now I'm trying to get back to that screen but I can only set up a Twitter or Facebook.

Can anyone tell me how to break the message up so it doesn't appear all on one line? I tried 'coding' a \n...seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I think you'll have a better luck connecting to AIM using pidgin. It is a very good chat client.

http://www.pidgin.im/download/ubuntu/